# How can I deploy commands to all guilds with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am writing a discord bot and I have a deploy-commands.js file. In it's current state it can only deploy the commands to one specific guild. I want it to deploy commands to all the guilds that the bot is in. How should I do this?

Here is the deploy-commands.js file:

````
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

console.log("Loading commands...");

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
    console.log("Loaded commands : " + command.data.name + "...");
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

console.log("Commands loaded...");

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

console.log('Successfully registered application commands to :');

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log(guild))
    .catch(console.error);

console.log('Done registering application commands!');```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace this lign

```js
  rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
```

by

```js
  rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(clientId), { body: commands })
```

By removing the `Guild` and `, guildId`, you now instead of posting your commands to a specific guild, post them globally on your bot.

**PS:** It takes about an hour for the entirety of the servers to have access to those slash commands so after deploying them, wait a little bit

Comment: Can we limit this to a specific list of guilds as well ?

Comment: @J.Volkya yes, just do a loop on the applicationGuildCommands, but you cant in one request put commands on multiple guilds unfortunatly if that's what you're asking for

Comment: yeah, now I have a list of allowed guilds in a config file, I load that at the start and in the commands I do a check to see if the guild is allowed to run the command.